# Modify style when JavaScript action is called - prettyPhoto lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, prettyphoto

When the javascript action below is called (prettyPhoto lightbox), I need to modify the style of the body to make overflow:hidden and position:fixed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']") .prettyPhoto({
    });
  });
</script>
```

So, I need to insert something like:

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
$('body').css('position','fixed');
```

...but ONLY when the lightbox is open.

Basically, I need to stop the body from scrolling while prettyPhoto is active.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some basic JavaScript code in the function wich opens prettyPhoto.
Like this:

```
document.getElementById(BodyId).setAttribute("class","body_noscrolling");
```

And make a css value for the body (.body) in wich you disable scrolling:

```
.body {
}  
.body_noscrolling {
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
}
```

Also change the `<body>` tag:

```
<body id="BodyId" class="body">
```

If you have a >CLOSE< button in your 'prettyPhoto', add this to the code of that button:

```
document.getElementById(BodyId).setAttribute("class","body");
```

I'm not really sure if it will work as I don't know how your prettyPhoto function is called.

Comment: First off, thank you.  I don't know much about javascript so this has been difficult to navigate.  Anyway, the full jquery.prettyPhoto.js is available here: https://github.com/scaron/prettyphoto/blob/master/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js  .... where do I put the document.getElementByID lines?

Comment: You could try placing 'document.getElementById(BodyId).setAttribute("class","body_noscrolling");' after line 118, and 'document.getElementById(BodyId).setAttribute("class","body");' after line 470. Again, I'm not sure if that works as I'm not able to try it myself.

Comment: didn't work. unfortunately. Thanks though!  Let me know if you think of anything else.